# use routes in two different component with click button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to display Quiz component content with path "/quiz" after I click button
and fetch component with path "/"

App jsx file:

```
 <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Fetch />} />
          {/* <Route path="/quiz" element={<Quiz />} /> */}
        </Routes>
      </Router>
```

Fetch jsx file

```
    <>
      {[...new Set(catData.map((c) => c.category))].sort().map((cat) => (
        // <Quiz cat={cat} setChoosenCat={setChoosenCat} choosenCat={choosenCat} />
        <div key={cat}>
          <Link to="/quiz" >
            <p onClick={() => handleClick(cat)}>{cat}</p>
          </Link>
        </div>
      ))}

      <Routes>
        {isClicked  && (
          <Route
            path="/quiz"
            element={
              <Quiz data={data}/>
            }
          />
        )}
      </Routes>

    </>
```

when I do this, the page route is change to /quiz but the page is empty and this error shows

```
No routes matched location "/quiz"
```

Answer (score 0):

you have the route commented out

```
 {/* <Route path="/quiz" element={<Quiz />} /> */}
```

remove the `{/*` at both ends or just replace that line with the following

```
<Route path="/quiz" element={<Quiz />} />
```

Comment: when I do this, the data I pass into the quiz component become undefine

Comment: have you imported the quiz component?

Comment: yes, the problem just with the data I pass.. it can read the data I pass in app jsx but in fetch component it doesn't